# Length undefined && ToString() undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a rails project in which I have a list of pharmacies that are generated from my database. I have a little bubble box within a map in that if i click on one of the pharmacies within my index table on my map a little bubble box pops up within the map.

The problem is that I have a list of url's that I am displaying within my bubble box. It looks quite nice, however It can cause a problem when I have a url that is quite too large. So what I am trying to do is limit the url that is displayed to a specific number of characters.

This is what I have within my JS

```
createMarkerBubble = (loc, i) ->
 hours = locationHours(loc)
 boxHtml = """
 <div class='pharmacy-box'>
   <div class='MarkerBubble'><h4>#{loc.name}</h4></div>
   <hr style="margin: 0.5em auto;" >
   <p>#{loc.address.address1}</p>
   <p>#{loc.address.city}, #{loc.address.state}, #{loc.address.zip}</p>
   <p><a href='#{loc.url}', target=_blank >  #{location.url | maxlength: 30 } #{location.url.length > 30 ? '....' : ''} </a></p>
   #{if hours? then "<p class='spacer'>#{hours}</p>"}
 </div>
 """
```

The problem is that my console shows an error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

When I saw this I assumed that the url was not a string, so I attempted `location.url.ToString().length > 30`

Yet going down this route, give me the error `Cannot read property 'ToString' of undefined`

So i'm wondering what is causing the error, and if there is any way I can restrict how much of the url is displayed?

Comment: It actually means that location.url is undefined... which is pretty weird... try exploring your location object. Or shouldn't you be using loc instead of location ?

Comment: agreed with @Martin. What does ```console.log('my location.url is ' + location.url)``` give you?

Comment: Oh my goodness.....i kept calling it as location instead of loc.  thank you so much!